# Why must the power series for the derivative of this be shifted over one unit?

Tags: calculus, power-series

I was asked to find the power series for $f(x) = \frac{x}{(1+7x)^2}$ I proceeded by finding the power series for  $g(x) = \frac{1}{1+7x}$, differentiating that series to get $g'(x) = \frac{-7}{(1+7x)^2}$, and mutiplying by $\frac{-x}{7}$ to get an equivalent answer. However, when looking at a solution to the problem, I saw that the power series for the power series for $g'(x)$ was shifted over by one unit to give:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-4)^nx^{n-1}$$

Why is the power series for $g'(x)$ shifted over here?

Comment: "shifted over": which part shifted which way by how much?

Comment: do you mean -7 or -4?

Comment: Is your series missing an exponent? Should it be $\sum_{n=1}^\infty -4^n \, x^{n-1}$? If so, are you asking why it's not written $\sum_{n=0}^\infty -4^{n+1} \, x^n$? If so, the answer is "It's the same series either way, just like writing $x^2 + 1$ or $1 + x^2$ as the polynomial that answers some question."

Comment: @EricTowers in the solution to the problem, the series for $g'(x)$ was written from n=1 to infinity instead of n=0 to infinity initially and I was trying to understand why

Comment: Consider what would happen in the sum for $g'$ if $n=0$. The term you get is just zero; that's because, in $g$, that $n=0$ term is a constant. So for simplicity, we just leave it off.

Comment: They probably shifted it so that, after multiplying by $x$, they'd get something with $x^n$.  Personally, I'd make the shift *after* multiplying by $x$, so that it's motivated.  (The reason that one *can* make the shift, regardless of *why*, is @JohnHughes's comment.)

Comment: @JohnHughes it was! I mistyped it. I was wondering why the person who solved the question started out with the above series then changed the instances of n to (n+1). Is there any reason for that, or is it arbitrary?

Comment: For reference, what I got for $g'$ and its series: notice if we admitted $n=0$, we would have a term of $0$. So $\sum_{n=0}^\infty$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty$ are both equally valid, the latter is just "more simplified" in other words:



$$g'(x) = \frac{-7}{(1+7x)^2} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n(-7)^n x^{n-1}$$

Comment: See Toby Bartels' remarks for a good guess, but we'll probably never know. Why do I sometimes write $1+ x^2$ and sometimes write $x^2 + 1$? Because sometimes I'm holding a teacup in my left hand and don't want to put it down to type the caret until I've taken a sip... [NB: it appears that the "-4" should be a "-7"; I wasn't checking the validity of the answer, merely showing that the two forms were representing the same series.]

Answer (score -1):

I don't see a problem.

$f(x)=\dfrac x{(1+7x)^2}=x(1+7x)^{-2}=x(1-14x+147x^2-...)=x-14x^2+147x^3-...$

$g(x)=\dfrac 1{1+7x}=1-7x+49x^2-343x^3...$

$g'(x)=-\dfrac 7{(1+7x)^2}=-7(1+7x)^{-2}=-7(1-14x+147x^2...)=-7+98x-1029x^2...$

$-\dfrac x7 g'(x)=f(x)=x-14x^2+147x^3....$